# echo 27 | netcat localhost 1234 | at now + 3 minutes works right away

Tags: shell, terminal, command-line-interface

I need to connect in 3 minutes with localhost and send a certain number, I know that you can call the command 
at now + 3 minutes 
and continue to write the command
echo 27 | netcat localhost 1234
Next input Cntr+D
And command will be add to the queue.
But I need to do this in one line.
Does anyone know a way how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Use quotes

```
echo "echo 27|netcat localhost 1234" | at now + 3 minutes
```

Comment: more info, please.